# Error with Mongo server registering user

Tags: swift, xcode, mongodb, heroku, swifty-json

In the app Im making theres a section to register a new user however when I click on register I get this error In xcode

Optional(Alamofire.AFError.responseSerializationFailed(Alamofire.AFError.ResponseSerializationFailureReason.jsonSerializationFailed(Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "Invalid value around character 0." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=Invalid value around character 0.})))

I'm using Heroku (Free Account) when I clicked on the link for my app is says 
"An error occurred in the application and your page could not be served. If you are the application owner, check your logs for details."

So When I go to view logs its says

"heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=smakchatapp.herokuapp.com request_id=26d5f7a0-2129-4ac6-9a05-146a607358dc fwd="67.215.141.133" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https"

So does that mean I just have to wait for the server to do its thing and wait till its back and running or is there something I can Do?

Comment: Seems like the error is happening on the web server side. Provide some more info on that; code, framework used etc.

Comment: It was actually on the server side. I waited a few mins and it fixed itself lol @AxelB